# Can I call specific fields and field groups in a node.tpl using Ajax

Tags: nodes, theming, ajax

I'm building a fairly large content type and some of what's in there doesn't need to be loaded until the user asks for it.

Is it possible to not load certain fields and field groups in the content type at first, but have them load via ajax and how would I do that in the `node.tpl` file?

Right now I have everything loaded and am doing a lot of hiding and showing, some of these are images and I'd rather not have the bandwidth hit on the user if there is a way I can load them asynchronously when asked for.

Comment: Not an answer, but you'll want to keep logic out of the template file if you can and instead use a node preprocess function. You might also want to clarify what you mean by "when asked for". What user action would take place in order to load these extra fields?

Comment: Basically when an element is clicked.